# Prevent refresh of my jsp page on error after clicking the save button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page where I have few text fields and after entering the data ,I need to save it .so while saving if there is any error ,the data which I had entered is getting refreshed.I need those fileds to be there without getting refreshed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code blocks which you have tried

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: sorry...since this is some private code ,I cant upload the code here..But the logic is like ,I have two functions-add(),save()..when add() is called I can add the details and when save () is called  need to save the details.but if there is some error in the data ,the details are getting refreshed.

Comment: try to make some mock codes and create a fiddle, so it will be easy to debug

Comment: @Dhanya Raj use client side `javascript` or `jquery` validations and if you are using `form` you can prevent the submission based on conditions. google it for sample form validation . Refer this example http://jsfiddle.net/swiftcoder/LLpE3/

Comment: I tried giving return false at the end of my onclick() ,but it doesnt worked for me

Comment: @DhanyaRaj _since this is some private code ,I cant upload the code here_ - then don't expect any help. We don't have crystal ball to look in and see, what is broken. If you want help with your code, you have to show it. Otherwise you can only get a very general advice.

Comment: Hi ..Pls help me in this...I think this is the problem with the hidden property..in the code they have given it as hidden .so is it because of this while error occurs the details is getting cleared?